# Python Twisted TCP application - How to prevent incoming message loss by blocking process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, twisted, zeromq

I have 10 messages/second(total activity) coming in on TCP from 40 clients.
I need to take each message and do a 5 second process (look up a webservice, do some DB queries and finally write the results to the DB).

How do I separate messages coming in from the slow 5 second process? Also I might receive another message from a client while already processing a message for that client. I NEVER want to lose a message.

Comment: What makes you think you are losing messages? If you are using TCP, there is queueing in the OS level. TCP is not a message oriented protocol, it is stream oriented. Bytes just pile up in a buffer until your application reads them. It's not like your application misses anything.

Comment: Eric you make a good point. I'll test that. I put my server to sleep and send in 150 messages. Then when it wakes up I'll check they arrived. To answer you question: Clients are complaining that messages "might" be going missing. I need to change things so we KNOW what is really happening.

Comment: I'm going to read up on TDD for Twisted. http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/core/howto/trial.html

Comment: Do you implement the client side part of the application? It should be relatively easy to check for 'missing' messages if that is the case.

Comment: Good question. I have no control of the client quality. They are given a simple text protocol to follow. They implement it themselves. A secondary goal is to find which clients are not working as expected. (the application owner will order a rebuild). I've started a little test server that runs a client through a series of tests. I've also started a virtual client that works in the ideal fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Twisted, the answer is to simply do what you want to do:

```
from twisted.python.log import err
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol

class YourProtocol(Protocol):
    ...
    def messageReceived(self, message):
        d = lookupWebService(message)
        d.addCallback(queryDatabase)
        d.addCallback(saveResults)
        d.addErrback(err, "Servicing %r failed" % (message,))
```

You can find APIs for interacting with web services in `twisted.web.client` (presuming "web services" are things you talk to using an HTTP client).  You can find APIs for interacting with some SQL database servers in `twisted.enterprise.adbapi`.  You can find APIs for interacting with other kinds of databases with a little googling.

Comment: That looks good. What is d exactly please? JP I want to kick off the tasks outside the Protocol. I only want the Protocol to pass on the message to the queue. I then could do something like above from the queue. The reason I don't want to kick off callbacks in the Protocol is I want to easily monitor what is happening to all tasks from the central point of the queue.

Comment: `d` is a `Deferred`.  I'm not sure what "queue" you're talking about.  I didn't use a queue because I didn't need one.

Comment: Thanks you JP. I'm looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

Distribute tasks in parallel using [Divide and Conqueur](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Divide-and-Conquer).

Lots of python examples illustrating this approach, read up here:

- Task Event: http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:taskvent
- Task Worker: http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:taskwork
- Task Sink: http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:tasksink

[image]

You can also distribute tasks using a ROUTER/DEALER proxy. Messages arriving at the proxy are fair-queued and distributed amongst downstream workers, no back chatter; this approach may better fit your needs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks raffian. At the moment I'm stuck what to do here: while True:
    msg = subscribe.recv(). If for example I setup a router/dealer - maybe OTT for what I'm doing - how would I control the number of workers to match the incoming workload?